# How can I write a macro to hide columns in a sheet based on a value in a different sheet in the same workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Looking to create a code to hide columns not needed? For example if sheet 1 H5 = 0 then I would want to hide columns B-AO in sheet 2 any guidance on this subject is greatly appreciated

I’ve tried if formulas and different VBA codes

Comment: `Sheet2.Columns("B:AO").Hidden = Sheet1.Range("H5").Value = 0`?

Comment: ...and use the `Worksheet_change` event to run that.

Comment: If `Sheet1!H5` contains a formula, please share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the columns to be hidden / unhidden *when the user types a value* (0 or otherwise) into cell H5 of Sheet1 (for clarity, this specific code will not work if H5 contains a formula) and assuming, for example, Sheet2 is not protected then, per the comments added by @BigBen and @Tim Williams, in the code-behind of Sheet1 (this code won't work if you put it anywhere else), add

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row = 5 And Target.Column = 8 Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pad Data Entry").Columns("B:AO").Hidden = Target.Value = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

... this code first tests if the changed cell is in row 5 and column 8 (8 being 'H') and, if so, sets the 'Hidden' state of the required columns in Sheet2 to be True (i.e. hidden) if the value in that cell is 0, or False (i.e. visible) if the value in that cell is anything other than 0.

> Update for revised requirement from OP (see comments below)

This is a much more complicated requirement hence I've left the original code, above, and added this new code. You need to replace the existing `Worksheet_Change` procedure with this. I have also added comments to the code to provide some explanation of how it works.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row = 5 And Target.column = 8 Then
        If IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
            ' get the number entered
            Dim lNum As Long
            lNum = CLng(Target.Value)
            With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Pad Data Entry")
                ' first, show all columns
                .Columns("B:AO").Hidden = False
                ' but if the number is from 0 to 9 (inclusive) then hide the relevant columns
                ' in groups of 4, starting from column B
                If lNum >= 0 And lNum <= 9 Then
                    .Range(.Columns(2 + lNum * 4), .Columns("AO")).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                End If
            End With
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Run time error 424 object required. I really don’t know what I’m missing i have changed the sheet name to what it is supposed to be. Basically what I am trying to achieve is say in setup in cell H5 your asking a qty

Comment: I assume the line `Sheet2.Columns ...` line is highlighted when you get the error? If so, what is the name of the Worksheet in which the columns are to be hidden?

Comment: Run time error 424 object required. I really don’t know what I’m missing i have changed the sheet name to what it is supposed to be. Basically what I am trying to achieve is say in setup in cell H5 your asking a qty and in data entry you have 10 different data sets which would be columns B:AO Say in setup in cell H5 you enter 0 then in data entry all 10 data sheets will be hidden if you were to enter 1 in setup H5 only one data sheet columns B:E will be visible and columns F:AO will still be hidden

Comment: Pad Data Entry is the name of the sheet to where the columns should be hidden. Well-Site Setup is where the cell is that is asking the quantity of data sheets need

Comment: That worked but when you try to unhide columns b:E and you try to hide them again and return setup H5 back to 0 they all show again do I need to write a separate code for each one? I have tried to continue with the code this workbook.worksheets(“pad data entry”).columns(F:AO”) .hidden =target.value = 1 so on and when I get to 9 it will in fact show 9 data sheets but any thing outside of 9 will show all and not hide them

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're meaning. However, if "that worked" then can I ask you to close this question (click the grey check mark) and ask a new one to clarify?

Comment: I really appreciate your help with this! Basically what is happening if I put the code in the way it’s written and I change the columns to be hidden from B:AO to F:AO and the target value goes up One it will show only One as it should when I Go back to 0 it shows all 10 I’m trying to get it to where when it default is set at 0 all data entry columns are hidden when 1 is entered in to H5 it shows One data column. If H5 = 2 then 2 data columns will show if you go back to zero it will hide the 2 columns again the code works only for one way not both ways.

Comment: HTH but what are the the 'data entry columns' ... trying to work it out from your comments, do columns B:AO contain 10 sets of 4 columns each? And when H5=0 then all are hidden; when H5=1 then F:AO is hidden; when H5=2 then J:AO are hidden etc?

Comment: In Pad data entry columns B:AO are all data columns in the well-Site setup tab is where you can enter in the quantity of data sheets needed for that specific job. In the pad data entry work sheet I have 10 pre made data sheets for the specific job I only need 3 i would then need the rest to be hidden and only show the 3 data set column’s

Comment: And that is correct 10 data sets 4 columns each

Comment: John quick question so I’m trying to carry the code string forward that you last wrote as I have more information with hiding other columns how can I carry this on with out compromising the whole code when I copy and paste the original code it will give me an ambiguous name error when I just copy from the second line down to end sub it don’t work just trying to expand the string I actually have a lot of information for the user to set up the work book for use multiple columns, cells, sheets etc any guidance or help with this is greatly appreciated